# How can I calculate flow length in QGiS/GRASS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, r, grass-gis

I have these rasters:

1. DEM
2. Flow Direction
3. Flow Accumulation

I would like to calculate the flow distance of **every** pixel to the outlet of a basin.

In Arc-GIS, I can use the flow length. But I don't have access to a license right now. Any other open source way to do it?

Comment: Dooku and Yoda. Funny.

Answer (score 7):

The GRASS addon [r.streams.distance](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.stream.distance.html) is what you need. You add it to GRASS 7 using the g.extension module to install addons.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SAGA tool for this. Look at this: http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_hydrology_6.html